# syntax error on POST auth-service.ts ionic 3 app

Tags: javascript, angular, post, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

im using ionic 3.20.0 , i have a error on this line

```
postData(credentials, type) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        let headers = new Headers();
        console.log(headers);

        this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers:headers}).
        subscribe(res =>{
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) =>{
          reject(err);
        });

      });
```

at auth-service.ts, the ts showing Syntax errors at `{headers:headers}`

why is this happening... the error stated

> Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>   Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>   Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>   Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>   Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

can any one guide me, i see in tutorial video, the guy not having the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added ‘HttpModule’ in your app.module.ts file.

You need to add ‘HttpModule’ in your app.module.ts as follows:

1] Import HttpModule as follows:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

2] Add HttpModule entry in imports:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule,
    ...
  ]
})
```